# Writing into an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

I have a method that needs to get years from an object and write that into an array. This is what I have so far:

```
    public int[] getYears() {   

    int[] years = null;

    for (RainfallYear rainfall : rainfallYears) {
        int year = rainfall.getYear();
        //insert year into int[] years array and return.
    }

    return years;
}
```

-

RainfallYear is an object that takes in a year and the values for rainfall during the months of the year:

```
public RainfallYear(int year, double[] rainfallMonths) {
    super();
    this.year = year;
    this.rainfallMonths = rainfallMonths;
}
```

This is how it would look like visually:

1914,50.9,87,115.8,32.3,47.1,56.6,97.1,63.9,48.1,62.4,110.3,190.8

rainfallYears is the name of an array of RainfallYear objects:

```
private RainfallYear[] rainfallYears = null;
```

I am struggling to insert the "extracted" year into an array to achieve the functionality of the int[] getYears method - to return an array of years.

---

Here is my previous attempt at doing this, but I don't think what I did was correct:

```
List<Integer> yearsList = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < rainfallYears.length; i++) {
        yearsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        yearsList.add(new RainfallYear(i, null).getYear());
    }

    int[] yearsArray = new int[yearsList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < yearsList.size(); i++) {
        yearsArray[i] = yearsList.get(i);
    }

    return yearsArray;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this `for` loop you create a new `ArrayList` for each iteration.

```
List<Integer> yearsList = null;
for (int i = 0; i < rainfallYears.length; i++) {
    yearsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    yearsList.add(new RainfallYear(i, null).getYear());
}

int[] yearsArray = new int[yearsList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < yearsList.size(); i++) {
    yearsArray[i] = yearsList.get(i);
}

return yearsArray;
```

take it out

```
List<Integer> yearsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < rainfallYears.length; i++) {
    yearsList.add(new RainfallYear(i, null).getYear());
}

int[] yearsArray = new int[yearsList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < yearsList.size(); i++) {
    yearsArray[i] = yearsList.get(i);
}

return yearsArray;
```

But that `ArrayList` seems useless since `yearsList.get(i)` will give you the "year" and that year is the `i` in `new RainfallYear(i, null)` and that `i` i goes from 0 to rainfallYears.length. 
So why don't you just do this instead :

```
int[] yearsArray = new int[rainfallYears.length];
for (int i = 0; i < rainfallYears.length; i++) {
    yearsArray[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Are you suggesting I should get rid of the ArrayList completely?

Comment: well it seems overkill since you're only taking the values beetween 0 and rainfallYears.length so if those are the values you want to put in the array then yes.

Comment: But in the third line of your code you are referring to yearsList.get(i).

Comment: Sorry for asking so much, but shouldn't there be somewhere a new RainfallYear within the code, since we are making a new object and using the method getYear on it?

Comment: like I said in the answer in the new RainfallYear(i,null) you are putting i, as the year then you get the year wich will give you back i. so that RainfallYear seems useless there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95754/discussion-between-vas87thrd-and-tahar-bakir).

Answer (score 1):

You are reinitializing your `yearsList` every iteration of the loop which will give it new data each time.

```
List<Integer> yearsList = null;
for (int i = 0; i < rainfallYears.length; i++) {
    yearsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    yearsList.add(new RainfallYear(i, null).getYear());
}
```

Instead, initialize your list outside of the loop like you did for your array.

```
List<Integer> yearsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < rainfallYears.length; i++) {           
    yearsList.add(new RainfallYear(i, null).getYear());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But just to get things clear, how would I insert the year into int[] years array in the first snippet of code?

Comment: You can't "insert" into an array like you can into a more advanced data structure, like a `List`. You can read/write elements at a given index: `int year = years[index]` or `years[index] = 1991`.